# How to deselect selected RadioButton

Tags: java, android

trying to deselect RadioButton when selected. I was suggested to use

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Radio_Group);
    radioGroup.clearCheck();
```

but when I use it in my code it blocks all RadioButtons so they can't be selected.

```
public void OnRadioButtonClick(View view)
{

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    switch (view.getId()) {
        case radioButton1: 


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "..." + String.valueOf(checked),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2: 

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "..." + String.valueOf(checked),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton3: 

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "...." + String.valueOf(checked),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Please use simple language in your explanations :) I'm new in programming.
Thanks.

Comment: Try using `radioGroup.check(-1);`

Comment: Also, why your first case statement is a radioButton itself instead of `R.id.radioButton1`?

Comment: hmm.. I don't really know but it works :) .I will change it. Where exactly implement 'radioGroup.check(-1);' in my code? Many thanks

Comment: Eduardo, when I place it  inside the code 'check' turns red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.setChecked(false);`.

For example:

```
//global variable, inside a class
boolean wasChecked;


public void OnRadioButtonClick(View view){

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    if(wasChecked && checked){
        ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);
        wasChecked = false;
    }else if(checked){
        wasChecked = true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here is the full solution:

```
boolean wasChecked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



public void OnRadioButtonClick(View view)
{

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();


    if(wasChecked && checked){
        ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);
        wasChecked = false;
    }else if(checked){
        wasChecked = true;
    }

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id. radioButton1:


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "..." + String.valueOf(checked),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "..." + String.valueOf(checked),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton3:

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "...." + String.valueOf(checked),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sudo. But the same question as above - where exactly implement your suggested method in my code'? Thank you.

Comment: @Beksa you can put it wherever you want to deselect a `RadioButton`.

Comment: Ok. gonna check it now.

Comment: When I put  '((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);'inside each case it blocks all Button from selecting.

Comment: @Beksa I think it doesn't block. When it's selected by you, it is instantly deselected by code, so you can't even notice a change.

Comment: Hahah :) you must be right but I want to **see it selected**, so by clicking I can **deselect it**, so it can **be selected** again :) And all this must be visible to the user :)

Comment: Here's a solution: **`if(checked)((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);`** *( from your code `checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();`)*

Comment: When I implement your 'if(checked)((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);' right below my 'boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();' it doesn't select anything just throws message 'true'

Comment: @Beksa, sudo is right. But AFAIK, radioButtons are made to have at least one selected. If you want to deselect when click, shouldn't you use checkbox instead?

Comment: @Beksa you must update your `checked`variable. Read again the value after changing it

Comment: You need a global variable to store each rb's last state (checked or not, for example for rb1 you can make `boolean wasSelected1;`), so when you click it, you do: `if(wasSelected1){ ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false); wasSelected1=false; }else{ wasSelected1=true; }` if case is  `R.id.radioButton1` and vice versa for each radio button.

Comment: I appreciate very much your help. The point is that I wanna make a quiz when only one answer must be selected therefore I've decided to use rb instead of checkboxes. I believe sudo's code is good but I just cant get it working in my code.

Comment: You can make a separate button to deselect all rbs - that will be easier

Comment: Sudo, could you please give me a whole code example just only with radioButton1? I get confused when trying to work it out myself.

Comment: you want an example for that wasSelected1 or for button to deselect all rbs?

Comment: Number 1 - just I have one out of three selected and I want to deselect that one so all three will be deselected/clear so any of these three can be selected again.

Comment: One second sudo. it's running slow. Gradle build still running

Comment: I know - gradle is always slow :)

Comment: Firstly, declare `wasChecked` directly in the **class**, not in the **method**. (move `boolean wasChecked;` outside `onCreate`) And you have redudant `}` after my `if -else if` block

Comment: OMG! SUDO! HOW CAN I THANK YOU? :) EVERYTHING WORKS PERFECTLY! You are the first person I've met on this website who was so eager to help!!! I wanna meet up with you and get you a beer or two :) How can I be in contact with you? :)

Comment: I recommend deleting your *"answer"*, because it is not really an answer

Comment: I wanna leave some appreciation to you here and I hope the above 'answer' won't do any 'damage' to this website :) Plenty of work ahead of me and fun with programming. Hope to meet you here again.